# Access response status code for successful requests using Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I need to be able to access the status code of a request. The call can be successful in either of two ways 200 or 201. This is obvious when calling via postman but using the web client, so far I haven't been able to determine which has occurred.

```
webClient.post()
        .uri(url)
        .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, bearerToken)
        .bodyValue(bodyMap)
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST::equals,
                response -> response.bodyToMono(String.class).map(Exception::new))
        .bodyToMono(Map.class)
```

I was thinking maybe I could set an integer variable using within the onStatus() lambda function. Is it even possible to access external variables within a lambda function?

```
int responseStatus;

// post call
.onStatus(
            HttpStatus.CREATED::equals,
            response -> ... // do something to set responseStatus
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.toEntity(Class<T> bodyClass)` method to get entity wrapped in response object `ResponseEntity<T>`

```
var response = webClient.post()
        .uri(uri)
        .retrieve()
        .toEntity(Map.class)
        .map(res -> {
            if (res.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                ...
            }

            return res.getBody();
        });
```